# How do you use codeigniter segments?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm new to codeigniter 2, and I have a question about URI segments.

What should I do when I have a different number of segments?

for example (pseudo code)

```
if(number of segments are 3){
   do something
}elseif(number of segmens are only 2){
  do something else
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of segments is really only relevant to the application and shouldn't really be in your code. You use them by assigning variables to them. So say you had an order list and you wanted the ability to edit it. You could have a url like myorders/edit_order/12 then in the controller you'd use that segment like this:

```
function edit_order()
{
   $this->load->helper->('uri'); // although I load this in the autoload.php since it gets used often
   $orderId = $this->uri->segment(2);
}
```

I really can't see a reason why you'd need to know the number of segments, just which segment holds the data you're passing.

Comment: My method will do different things depending on the number of segments.

for example

sport/league/team

will post articles for team

while sport/league/
will post articles for the league etc.

just an example.

Comment: Fair enough, not exactly how I'd do it, especially because it really locks you in to that scheme, whereas say feeding it /sport or /team then posting articles based on $postType = $this->uri->segment(2) would allow you to use anything in that second segment and do your post search based on that.

Comment: Let me ask another question while you're here. How do i remove the index method in routes?

instead of getting index/sport/league/team i want to remove index and still get the content.

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html It's in there, it's also posted all over the place. You need to edit the htaccess file that is in the applications root. Meaning the one that is in the main folder, not the one inside the application folder. When you look at it in Explorer you should see the .htaccess, and the application and system and user_guide folders (among other things.) This is the one thing they seem to leave out, there are multiple .htaccess files and they don't ever say which it is you need to edit.

Comment: i removed the index.php in .htaccess. do i have to do the same with the index from an crontroller ?

I've been trying to add some routes but i don't get any changes

Comment: You might want to create a new question for this and show your controller code because it sounds like we're talking about two different things. If you are running this from a controller called index then you could do something like this in your routes.php $route['^(?!index).*'] = "index/$0"; That should route /sport to /index/sport

Comment: Oh, dude im really sorry but i ment if my method is called sport or something and the segments are sport/index/football/ or sport/index/football/MLS how do i get the index away then? Sorry for beeing so disturbing :P

Comment: Okay, the way the routes work is what is on the left side is what you want to show up in the url and what is on the right side is where it points to. So let's say for example you wanted sports/index/football to show up in the address bar as mywebsite.com/football you would add the route: $route['football'] = 'sports/index/football'; You would do this for each of the routes you want to change. Keep in mind the uri thing works off what is actually in the address bar and not the actual path, so this is going to change your thinking on how to do things.

Comment: lol well, glad you got it sorted. You should click accept on that guys answer though to give him the recognition for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [URL classes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) `total_segments()`

```
//Returns the total number of segments.
if ($this->uri->total_segments() == 3) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```